# Stored procedure go to infinite loop

Tags: mysql

I am making a stored procedure in order to check that whether a user exists or not. The problem is whenever I pass it the correct username, it executes successfully but when I pass wrong username, it go through an infinite loop.

Where am I going wrong? Here is my Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `VerifyUserNPass`(userParam varchar(50), out result int)
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE tempUser varchar(50) default '';
    DECLARE count int default 0;
    DECLARE noRows int;

    DECLARE userList cursor for select userName from users;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    select count(*) into noRows from users;

    OPEN userList;
    read_loop: LOOP
        FETCH userList into tempUser;
        IF tempUser = userParam THEN
                SET @count = count + 1;
                LEAVE read_loop;
        ELSEIF count > noRows THEN
                LEAVE read_loop;
        END IF;

    END LOOP;
    CLOSE userList;

    select count into result;

END
```

Comment: You have a mixture of references to user variables (`@count`) and procedure variables `count`. There's no need for the `noRows` variable, or any tests on it. Use the `done` variable to determine if you've processed all the rows, rather than running a separate query to get a count of the rows. It would be more efficient to include a WHERE clause on the query to return only rows where the userName matches the value of userParam.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your code, use a conditional test on the `done` variable to determine whether to leave the loop.  (The `done` variable is initialized to FALSE, and then set to TRUE in the CONTINUE HANDLER when there are no more rows.)

Get rid of the query "`count(*)`" query, and the `noRows` variable; those are not needed. (In a concurrent system, it's possible for that count(*) query to return a value that differs from the number of rows returned by a later query. (Consider that its possible for other sessions to insert or delete rows while your procedure is running.)

Also get rid of the references to the `@count` user variable. You have a mixture of references, to both a *user* variable `@coount` and a *procedure* variable `count`. These are independent variables. There's no need for your procedure to use a *user* variable. Instead, stick with using variables that are declared in your procedure. (Save the user variables for when you have a need.)

```
-- select count(*) into noRows from users;
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH userList into tempUser;
    IF done THEN
       LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    IF tempUser = userParam THEN
        SET count = 1;
        LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
END LOOP;
```

---

A more efficient way to code this would be to let the database find the row(s) you are interested in, by adding a WHERE clause on your query. (There's no need for you to fetch rows that aren't going to match the condition you are interested in.)

Modify your cursor definition to include a predicate (i.e. a condition in a WHERE clause) to limit the rows returned:

```
DECLARE userList cursor for select userName from users
  WHERE userName = userParam LIMIT 1;
```

---

I don't understand the need for a procedure here. A native SQL statement would be much more efficient, e.g.

```
SELECT 1 AS found FROM users u WHERE u.userName = 'foo' LIMIT 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you increment your loop counter for all branches not only in the succes branch and have result variable to hold your outcome.

```
DECLARE userFound int default 0;
......
read_loop: LOOP
    FETCH userList into tempUser;
    SET @count = @count + 1;
    IF tempUser = userParam THEN
           SET @userFound = 1
           LEAVE read_loop;
    ELSEIF count > noRows THEN
            LEAVE read_loop;
    END IF;
    .....
    select userFound into result;
```

And I would expect that this would return the same result (but I'm not an [MySql expert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select-into.html))

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `VerifyUserNPass`(userParam varchar(50), out result int)
BEGIN
 select COUNT(userName) into result from users where username = @userParam
END
```

Comment: I thought that COUNT variable returned the RESULT where 1 = true (exists) and 0 = false (does not exist)?

Comment: Yep. I only answer the question, but it definitely has more issues :-)

Comment: Hey Maybe your right? I was just guessing  as the code block was formatted badly.